# simple Navigation using node js without any frameworks

Tags: node.js, navigation

When i read "login.html" in app.js  which  has two href links(login & signup) which should redirect to the location provided but it is not happening when i click them ?? 
here goes the code

```
var http = require('http');
   var fs = require('fs');       
http.createServer(function (req, res) {

  fs.readFile('./login.html' , function(err, data){


if(err){
    console.log(err);
}


console.log("sanjay");


res.end(data);
}); 



}).listen(3000);
console.log('Server running at http://<workspace-url>/');
```

"login.html"

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>


<ul>

<li><a href="index.html" >login</a></li>
<li><a href="index.html">signup</a></li>

</ul>



</body>




</html>
```

Comment: Please provide more information.  What does your server do? What URLs? What do you see in the console?

Comment: i updated the code and am able to read that file but unable to redirect to index.html when i click on login/signup.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app.js file is only serving `login.html`, it's not handling a request for `index.html`.

You can modify app.js a bit like this:

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  if (req.url === '/index.html') {
    fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/index.html').pipe(res)
  } else {
    fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/login.html').pipe(res)
  }
}).listen(3000)
```

Comment: Any time!
Also, as things get larger you may want to use a module that helps handle these routes.

I prefer using [patterns](https://github.com/watson/patterns#example-a-complete-http-router) for known routes and [ecstatic](https://github.com/jfhbrook/node-ecstatic) for assets.

Comment: Sure am at very beginning these might help me to achieve thank you :)

Comment: hey @Jekrb how to manipulate so many files becoz i may have so many files in header or footer is there any way to handle that

Comment: You can use ecstatic for this: https://github.com/jfhbrook/node-ecstatic#stock-http-server

Answer (score 0):

A nodejs server does not automatically serve ANY files.  You have code to serve login.html, but you don't have any code to serve any other files.  So, as your server is written, all requests will serve login.html, no matter what URL was requested.

If you want to stick with the plain http server you have, then you will have to look at the `req` parameter to see what the requested path was and then serve an appropriate file.  But, there are simple frameworks like Express that make this much simpler to serve a number of static HTML files with one line of code.

The request object is [documented here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_incomingmessage) and you could look at `req.url` if you want to see what url was requested and then serve the appropriate file.

I would personally recommend that you use the [Express framework](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app) where you can use the `express.static()` functionality to serve your static HTML files with one line of code.